# Powershell print sub-level objects in FT

Tags: powershell, object, azure-powershell

I have the following generic structure:

- Powershell command returns an object containing named fields and values. Some of those values are objects with another struct of names and values below them.
- I want to simply print the results in a FL, but I want the sub-object values included.

The following code provides me the output I'm looking for, but I feel like I'm not doing this in a powershell-efficient way and I should be able to pipe this into a one-liner

```
foreach ($user in (Get-MsolUser | ?{$_.StrongAuthenticationmethods -ne $null})){
Write-host "$($user.UserPrincipalName) :: $($user.DisplayName)"
foreach($method in $user.StrongAuthenticationMethods){
write-host "`t$($method.MethodType)"
}}
```

I was hoping the above could be shortened to resemble the below non-functional code... is something like this possible to dump the property values when there could be a number of results between 0-X (max 4 in my case)?

```
Get-msolUser|?{$_.StrongAuthenticationmethods -ne $null} | select UserPrincipalName,Displayname,isLicensed,(StrongAuthenticationmethods | fl)
```

Comment: I commend to your attention the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet, and specifically the `-ExpandProperty` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```
Get-MsolUser |
  Where-Object { $null -ne $_.StrongAuthenticationmethods } | 
  Select-Object UserPrincipalName, Displayname, isLicensed, @{
    Name='StrongAuthenticationmethods'
    Expression={ $_.StrongAuthenticationmethods.MethodType -join "`n" }
  } |
  Format-List
```

The above uses [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) (`fl`), but if you prefer a *tabular* representation via [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) (`ft`) instead, replace `| Format-List` with `| Format-Table -Wrap`.